# What is the additive identity of a quotient module?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

Given a module $M$ and a submodule $S$, the additive identity of $M/S$ is $0+S=S$. Does this mean that there are two additive identities? $0$ and $S$? Why must we write the equation $0+S=S$ instead of just $S$?

Comment: There's always one additive identity, which you can write as $0$, but which *as a coset* is $0 + S = S$. You may find it less confusing to write $[m]$ for the coset $m + S$, in which case the additive identity is $[0]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements of the quotient module $M/S$ are *cosets* of the submodule $S$, i.e. sets of the form
$$m+S:=\{m+s:s\in S\}$$
where $m\in S$. (Two elements $m,n$ determine the same coset iff $m-n\in S$.)

So, $0$ is the zero element of $M$, and its coset, $0+S=S$ is the zero element of $M/S$.